# C++ Class and Function Template declarations?

Tags: c++, function, templates

Right now I am trying  to make my template class and functions run but I am not sure how to define a template void function. Here's a small part of my code attached below. The code doesn't run and for anytime in the class arrayList is used it says `argument list for arrayList is missing`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Type> //Template class declaration 
class arrayList
{
public:
    void print() const;

protected:
    int *list;                          //array to hold the list elements
    int length;                         //to store the length of the list
    int maxSize;                        //to store the maximum size of the list
};

template<typename Type>
void arrayList::print() const
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cout<<list[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Which part of your post represents the *minimal*  in "minimal, compilable example"?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
template<typename Type>
void arrayList<Type>::print() const ...
```